# Как импортировать настройки AndroidStudio?

Tags: android-studio

Вот такая ситуация я долго работал на своем ноуте по Linux но теперь поменял его на Mac и вот думаю , придется ли теперь заново подключать плагины и устанавливать все настройки или можно как то импортировать это все?

Тем более я правда пока не знаю зачем и как это работает, но студия предложила войти использовав гугл аккаунт и я это сделал. Теперь в правом верхнем углу есть мой аватар и я подозреваю, что какае то синхронизация должна быть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В основном меню студии есть кнопки `Import/Export settings` - при экспорте формируется `jar` файл с настройками, который можно на другой машине импортировать - так значительная часть настроек применится. Не знаю на счёт плагинов, но всякие штуки типа форматирования кода точно переносятся.

Comment: кстати Юрий а вы не знаете зачем есть возможность подключать студию к гугл аккаунту? Как у меня на скрине показано...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, я не знаю)

Comment: Теперь это File->Manage IDE Settings